# How to add warning on a combo box selection?

Tags: angular, typescript, search, combobox, warnings

So, I have an existing combo box where a user can type and search for existing options inside the combo box. What I want to do is to add a warning whenever the user type words that does not belong to the options inside the combo box.
Here is my code right now:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1">
                <mat-label>Aircraft Type (ICAO)</mat-label>
                <!-- test autocomplete aircraft type -->
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Aircraft Type (ICAO)"
                  aria-label="Aircraft Type (ICAO)"
                  matInput
                  formControlName="aircraftType"
                  [matAutocomplete]="type"
                  (input)="onAircraftTypeChange()"
                />
                <mat-autocomplete
                  #type="matAutocomplete"
                  (optionSelected)="onSelectAircraftType($event.option.value)"
                  [displayWith]="displayAircraftTypeFn"
                >
                  <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let type of filteredAircraftTypes | async"
                    [value]="type"
                  >
                    {{ type.label }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
                <!-- end test autocomplete -->
              </mat-form-field>
```

[image: existing combo box]

I would like to add the warning above the form field.

Comment: Place warning/error message above form field will lead to user surprise behaviour which violates the [Principle of Least Surpise](https://www.userfocus.co.uk/articles/the-principle-of-least-surprise.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can show warning message like below code

```
<div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Just need to add `<mat-error>` inside `<mat-form-field>`

Answer (score 0):

Would not recommend that placing a warning or error message above the form field as it leads to user surprise behavior and **violates the [Principle of least surprise](https://www.userfocus.co.uk/articles/the-principle-of-least-surprise.html)**.

Instead, when the user inputs the text and the options don't contain the particular text, the `<mat-autocomplete>` dropdown will not show any options, and hence it is okay to show the `<mat-error>` below the `<matInput>` element.

---

> .component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1">

    <mat-label>Aircraft Type (ICAO)</mat-label>
    <!-- test autocomplete aircraft type -->
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Aircraft Type (ICAO)"
      aria-label="Aircraft Type (ICAO)"
      matInput
      formControlName="aircraftType"
      [matAutocomplete]="type"
      (input)="onAircraftTypeChange()"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #type="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectAircraftType($event.option.value)"
      [displayWith]="displayAircraftTypeFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of filteredAircraftTypes | async" [value]="type">
        {{ type.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <!-- end test autocomplete -->

    <mat-error *ngIf="f.aircraftType.errors">
      <mat-error *ngIf="f.aircraftType.errors['notFound']">Not found!</mat-error>
    </mat-error>

</mat-form-field>
```

Access built-in `valueChanges` Observable for `airCraftType` control:

1. `startWith` - Set initial value with empty string.
2. `mergeMap` - Filter options based on inputted text.
3. `tap` - Task to `setError` for `airCraftType` control if (2) returns empty array. Otherwise, clear the error.

> .component.ts

```js
import { mergeMap, map, Observable, of, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
  ...

  this.filteredAircraftTypes = this.form.controls[
      'aircraftType'
    ].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      mergeMap(value => this._filter(value)),
      tap(filterOptions => {
        this.form.controls['aircraftType'].markAsTouched();
        this.form.controls['aircraftType'].markAsDirty();

        if (filterOptions.length == 0) {
          this.form.controls['aircraftType'].setErrors({ notFound: true });
        } else {
          this.form.controls['aircraftType'].setErrors(null);
        }
      })
    );
}

private _filter(value: string): Observable<IAirCraft[]> {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.aircraftTypes.pipe(
      map(options =>
        options.filter(option =>
          option.label.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
        )
      )
    );
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qe5zcr)

---

### References

[Adding a custom filter - Autocomplete | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter)

[startWith - Learn RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith)

Answer (score -1):

Add a span above form field and show it when the length of filteredList array is 0.

Comment: can you elaborate please